# Jquery automatically select next X checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm working on a website for a theater where a customer can reserve tickets.
Choosing a chair works as follows:

1. You select how many chairs you want in the dropdown menu (we will call this X).
2. You tick the checkboxes where you want to sit (maximum of X).
3. Upon having chosen all X checkboxes, the other checkboxes turn grey (unclickable).

There are ofcourse also chairs that have already been reserved. These simply don't have a checkbox. The value of the checkbox is the same as the chair's unique ID.

This works fine except I want the system to automatically tick the next checkboxes (next 3 if the customer has chosen 4).

I have updated my code to this:

```
    var _X = $('#PlaatsenDropdown').val() - 1;
    var _id = $(this).id;
    var _counter = _id + _X;

    for(var i = _id; i <= _counter; i++) {
        if($(this).nextAll().is('disabled')) {
            alert('No seats available');
        } else {
            alert('Chairs available');
        }
    }
```

The id is also the chair number, so I just take that and do some calculations with it to use in the for loop.
This however, doesn't show me anything. I think there might be something wrong with the calculations but I can't figure out what :S.

Comment: @deed02392 I've checked the JQuery documentation but can't seem to find how to use this for multiple elements. Can I just use .next(X)?

Comment: I thought you could but no. Looking at your code, I think the error is in you are doing an `.is()` on an array, which will always return false.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=072j1t0zN1

Comment: @deed02392 When I click the link it asks me if I want to join the collaberatio session. Regardless of what I click everything is empty :S.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of ID strings similar to what you've done already.  Then loop through the array with the 'disabled' test.

Pseudo code:

```
val = selected_chair_ID
for (i=0; i < desired_number_chairs; i++) {  
    search_right.push('#' + val + i);
    search_left.push(('#' + val - i);
}
found = true;
for (j = 0; j < search_right.length; j++) {  //  Check chairs to the right
    $(search_right[j]).....// Disabled check
    if (disabled...) {
        found=false;
    }
if (!found) {
    check chairs to the left 
}
if (!found) // out of luck
```

Comment: I think alot of this code can be replaced by using the jquery .nextAll() function. Can you check my updated code?(in the original question). I think it's closer to being done now but it's always returning the else.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get this code at all. It seems like half is missing and you have a double check if found is set or not.

Comment: 'Half missing' - yes you are right.  That's why I proceeded it with 'Pseudo code:'.  I just meant to give him an example of how to search, first right, then left, and then if neither found - out of luck.

to user1433479 - I'll check out the nextAll().  I haven't used that yet.